# How to add SSH key to PuTTY Agent at startup in Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-service, putty, ssh-agent

I need to add a private SSH key to Putty Agent (pagent.exe) every time a Windows server starts up -- before a user logs on interactively. The key is to be used by a service.

If it was a regular user that needed to use the key, I would just place a shortcut in the Startup folder, however, this does not work on a server, because no user logs in.

I need this on Windows Server 2008 as well as Windows Server 2003.

I figure this must be a pretty common use case as public key authentication with SSH and SFTP becomes more widespread.

Answer (score 21):

You can provide a path to the key on the Target command line in the shortcut

- Create a shortcut to put in startup.
- Right click -> properties
- Modify the `Target:` section to add the key

  `C:\Program Files\putty\pageant.exe C:\Program Files\putty\keys\iain.ppk`

When your system starts pageant will load the key and if it requires a pass phrase to unlock it it will ask for it.

You can add multiple keys on the pageant command line too e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\putty\pageant.exe C:\keys\iain.ppk c:\keys\user1.ppk
```

Comment: Will this work for servers on which users never logs in?

Comment: If the keys don't have a pass phrase then yes. If they do have a pass phrase then someone needs to supply it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this step: "Create a shortcut to put in startup." What startup folder do you mean here? Normally startup folders are related to a specific user and only run when said user logs in, right?

Comment: The lines above could just as easily be put in a batch file couldn't they?

Comment: Sure, but how do I make sure that the bat file is run on server startup? Even when no users are logged in?

Comment: You could use the builtin "Task Scheduler" which allows you to execute programs at various times, for example system startup.